# How to Fix it When PropertyGrid work with and List<T> in C# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = a;
    }
    private readonly A a = new A();
}
internal class A
{
    public A()
    {
        if (Bs == null)
        {
            Bs = new List<B>();
        }
    }
    public List<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
internal class B
{
    public B()
    {
        Name1 = string.Empty;
        Name2 = string.Empty;
    }
    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
}
```

I was going to show the picture,but I can't,it remind me have no enough reputation.
The Question is:

1)How to make "WindowsFormApplication1.B" displayed as Name1's value,or Name2's value, or their combination?

2)How to hide the quetion mark button on the right and upper corner?Or just repond to its Click?

Here is the picture link:
[ImageHere](http://i42.tinypic.com/14tao0w.png)

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you describe more what you are trying to do? Re displaying particular values - usually than means you *give the properties those values*

Comment: you can post a link to your snapshot though.

Comment: I wish I can show the image when the program is running.When the program runs,the propertygrid show a item "Bs",click the "...",then a Form appears,then i click the "Add",it show a item named "WindowsFormApplication1.B" added to the list,here is the first question laid on.the appeared Form's right and upper corner shows a question mark button,but is doesn't reponse to my click,it is the second question laid on.all code has been shown except draging a propertygrid control to the form.

Comment: I am trying the link of picture,hold on.

Comment: here the picture is:<a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=14tao0w" target="_blank"><img src="http://i42.tinypic.com/14tao0w.png" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>

Comment: hey, as I can see, your snapshot doesn't show any problem, the PropertyGrid shows the properties of your a object properly.

Comment: thank you for all your answer.As I Questioned, "WindowsFormApplication1.B"is not a good name to show a item,and the question mark button does not respond to my click.I'd like to hide it or I'd like to handle the click event.